# IntelliJ: Stop execution at breakpoint for single file component using jest and Vue.js2

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, intellij-idea, vuejs2, jestjs

## Goal

Stop execution at breakpoint while debugging a unit test for a `single file component` in `IntelliJ` using `Vue.js2` and `jest 27` (and above)

## Expected result

Stop execution at defined breakpoint

## Actual result

Test finishes without pausing at defined breakpoint

## Description

In `Vue.js2`, assume I have a `single file component` called `a.vue`. The corresponding tests are located in `a.spec.ts`.

When I set a breakpoint for `a.vue` and debug a unit test, then `IntelliJ` will not stop at any breakpoint.

If I do the same for another none sfc file, let's say `b.ts`, the execution will stop.

If I put `debugger;` in `a.vue`, it will stop execution at **any** line.

## I'm using

- `Jest` Testing Framework
- `Vue.js 2`
- `IntelliJ`
- `Node interpreter 14 LTS`

## I've tried

- Set option `transform { '^.+\\.vue$': '@vue/vue2-jest' }` in `jest.config.file`
- Pass Node option `--inspect-brk` via `edit configurations...` (Execution never returns)
- Set option `transform { '^.+\\.vue$': '@vue/vue2-jest' }` in `jest.config.file`

## Question

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the issue only occur when debugging Jest? Can you debug your `a.vue` using the instructions in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.2/vue-js.html#vue_running_and_debugging_debug? please check your `jest.config.js` - what does it look like? Do you have `collectCoverage` enabled in it?
If the source file is instrumented for coverage, the generated code can't be correctly mapped to source; it's a well known limitation